# How do I use an .env file to connect to a Postgresql database in Intellij?

Tags: database, postgresql, docker, environment

The .env file has the following info:
POSTGRES_USER=admin
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=admin

My Postgresql is running inside Docker. I now need to connect my Intellij with the database running inside Docker.
I've connected to Postgresql in the past using the full Postgresql url but never with an .env file inside Docker.

Is this related to the Dockerfile maybe?
I'm a Docker and Postgresql newbie

Answer (score 0):

Use following command to run the postgres docker container with the env file.`--env-file` argument use to point the env file:

```
docker run 
    --name postgresdb
    -p 5432:5432 
    --env-file <path_to_env>
    -d 
    postgres
```